# How can we match string contains any value of array in C# w/o using loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string, contains

How can we match string contains any value of array in C# w/o using loop?

For example:

string[] abc= [val1,val2,val3] .
string xyz= "demo string to check if it contains any value in abc array that is val2";

I want to check if any value of array abc exists in string xyz w/o using loop

Comment: `if (abc.Contains("xyz"))`?  Contains() internally uses a loop, but that is hidden from you.

Comment: There is no way to make it without a loop. Maybe you can hide the loop one level deeper by using LINQ or writing your own (extension) method, but somewhere you have to loop.

Comment: your debate made me to think why SO didn't implemented functionality to double dislike someone's copied answer :P haha

Answer (score 2):

one aproach may be linq

```
string[] abc = { "abc", "def", "xyz" }; 
string xyz = "demo string to check if it contains any value in abc array that is val2";
bool result = abc.Any(xyz.Contains); //true
```

but internal linq and contains uses loop - so i think there is no possible solution without a loop.

Answer (score 1):

To search from/in a collection (read array), you need to use loops/iteration because collection is involved.

Even if you do not write a loop and write some syntactic sugar code, in the background it will use LOOP/ITERATION.

As others answered you can use LINQ or something but it will iterate over your collection.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a contains function. you may use it like this

```
bool result=abc.Contains("walue to be checked");
```

Alternate way is by using LINQ

but both the method use internal loops.

Answer (score 0):

you can check as :

```
string[] arr = { "abc", "bcd", "cde" };

if (arr.Contains("abc"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
}
```

For faster way you can use [Array.IndexOf Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
int pos = Array.IndexOf(arr, "abc");
if (pos > -1)
{
    // the array contains the string and the pos variable
    // will have its position in the array
}
```